# Why is GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE different between WebGL and Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, webgl

My WebGL's `ALIASED_POINT_SIZE` (in Safari and Chrome) is 33901.

On the other hand, in my native OpenGL (on Mac/Cocoa), it is just (1,64).

Why are the two values different? And is there no way to increase `gl_PointSize`?

Comment: It's not 33901. Your maximum framebuffer isn't even 33901 pixels wide in WebGL. That's just the constant that you are supposed to query the value of.

Answer (score 2):

`gl_PointSize` is a global you set in your vertex shader to set the size of the next point to be rasterized. You can set it anyway you please, from a constant (all points will be the same size), from a uniform (all points will be the same size that you can set at runtime), from an attribute (every point will be a different size depending on the per point data you supply), from some equation, etc (every point will be a different size depending on your equation).

`ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE` is a constant value you pass to `glGetIntegerv` in OpenGL and `gl.getParameter` in WebGL that returns the range of point sizes your GPU/Driver supports.

Note that WebGL and OpenGL ES 2.0 only require a max point size of 1.0. That means if you count on points be able to render larger than 1 pixel you'll need to find some other solution on certain hardware. You can [see the supported sizes near the bottom of this page](http://webglstats.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at two different values:

- 33901 (or 0x846d in hex) is the value of `GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE`, which is an **enum value** used to **query** the point size range.
- (1, 64) must be a point size range you already queried.

In native OpenGL, you would query the point size range with:

```
GLint range[2];
glGetIntegerv(GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, range);
```

I haven't used WebGL, but based on the documentation the corresponding call there should be:

```
gl.getParameter(gl.ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE)
```